How to align forests vertically with surrounding words?
here is my code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    default preamble={
        for tree={%
            grow=north,
            circle,
            fill,
            minimum size=2.5pt,
            inner sep=0pt,
        },
    }
}
\begin{document}
some \begin{forest} [] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[]] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[[] []]] \end{forest} words 
\end{document}

compiling with pdflatex, I got

I want them to align vertically with words, like this (I made this by ps)

what should I do?

Add
/tikz/baseline=(current bounding box.center),

to your default preamble. That is,
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    /tikz/baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    for tree={%
      grow=north,
      circle,
      fill,
      minimum size=2.5pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
  }
}

Edit
Here's the output I get:

Complete code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    /tikz/baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    for tree={%
      grow=north,
      circle,
      fill,
      minimum size=2.5pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
some \begin{forest} [] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[]] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[[] []]] \end{forest} words
\end{document}

Edit 2
If you want it aligned relative to the current font, that's slightly trickier. This uses the font's xheight, but we have to leave the picture in order to get the value because, outside nodes, the current font is the null font.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728371/
\newdimen\myshiftaligndimen
\makeatletter
\forestset{
  declare dimen register={shift align},
  shift align'=0pt,
  default preamble={
    TeX={%
      \pgfinterruptpicture
      \myshiftaligndimen=\fontdimen2\font@name
      \global\myshiftaligndimen\myshiftaligndimen
      \endpgfinterruptpicture
    },
    /tikz/baseline={([yshift=-\myshiftaligndimen]current bounding box.center)},
    for tree={%
      grow=north,
      circle,
      fill,
      minimum size=2.5pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
some \begin{forest} [] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[]] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[[] []]] \end{forest} words
\end{document}

Or use 0.5\myalignshiftdimen or whatever proportion you prefer.

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728371/
\usepackage{forest}
\newdimen\myshiftaligndimen
\makeatletter
\forestset{
  declare dimen register={shift align},
  shift align'=0pt,
  default preamble={
    TeX={%
      \pgfinterruptpicture
      \myshiftaligndimen=\fontdimen2\font@name
      \global\myshiftaligndimen\myshiftaligndimen
      \endpgfinterruptpicture
    },
    /tikz/baseline={([yshift=-0.5\myshiftaligndimen]current bounding box.center)},
    for tree={%
      grow=north,
      circle,
      fill,
      minimum size=2.5pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
some \begin{forest} [] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[]] \end{forest} words some \begin{forest} [[[] []]] \end{forest} words
\end{document}


Thanks for your answer. I did so, and the two/three layers trees are aligned as my wish, the first tree also stayed below :(

@Syvshc please see edit above. how does the result differ from the alignment you want? I thought you wanted the trees always aligned so their vertical centres aligned to the baseline of the surrounding text. that's what this does.

@Syvshc not sure what ps is using, but I added examples with a shift of x-height and half x-height by way of demonstration. adjust as desired.
